Cython function accepting memoryview breaks at runtime
I have a small cython wrapper around some C++ code, which should accept numpy arrays as inputs to the python interface, and loop over them quickly as memoryviews internally. However I get this error every time I try to have a function that takes memoryviews:
AttributeError: module 'mymodulename' has no attribute 'memoryview'
Simplest example that causes the error:
In __init__.pyx:
cdef double c_arr_func(double[:] a):
    return a[1]

def arr_func(a):
    return c_arr_func(a)

def control_func(x):
    return x

Which compiles fine, and but throws the given error as soon as it is imported from test.py:
import mymodulename

AttributeError: module 'mymodulename' has no attribute 'memoryview'
There is no problem if only control_func is defined - the cython compiler is working fine, but the error always happens if c_arr_func is defined.
I am vexed, please help.

I suspect this is something to do with the module being called __init__, so perhaps name it something else. You can always create an __init__.py file that just imports from your cython module to get the interface you want. But also, if you think that this is a bug reporting it to https://github.com/cython/cython/issues is more productive than asking here
